# In FTP protocol, how do I know when a file upload is really done?

Tags: ftp, ftp-client, pureftpd

I get STOR (store) commands and APPE (append) commands.

The STOR might upload a complete file.

But it might be just part of a file, the rest comes later with multiple APPE commands.

How do I know when a file is really 100% uploaded?

Comment: AFAIK, the client is free to append at any time, so unless you wrote, or have intimate knowledge of, the client, you can't really tell on the server.

Comment: is there like a standard timeout then? Do I wait 30 mins? or 3 hours?

Comment: The question does not make sense. If you have a random file locally on a file system. How do you tell that it is complete? You do not. There's no way. And it's the same for FTP.

Comment: oh c'mon Martin, the question makes more sense than your example. In an FTP situation I need to process a file after it's been uploaded. I need to know when the user is done sending all the bits.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I know when a file is really 100% uploaded?

There is only end-of-transfer in FTP and not end-of-file. Commonly STOR is to used to transfer complete files and APPE is only used if the previous STOR broke somehow - but you never can be sure. If you need to be sure you have to built your own signalization for a finished file.